# What is the difference between SIGCLD and SIGCHLD signals?

Tags: unix, signals

I want to know what is the basic difference between SIGCLD and SIGCHLD signals? Are these just different names for the same signal on different architectures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Today, it's an alias, the exact system signal.  Fact is, SIGCLD was the System V name for the today, SIGCHLD.

Historically, SIGCHLD originated on BSD and was the name adopted by POSIX.  Based on System V SIGCLD the only differences happens when the signal is set to SIG_IGN:

BSD would generate zombies, System-V wouldn't.